Does Zscaler has api endpoints to Backup configurations?
Does Zscaler has exposed api endpoints to backup configuration or any python library available to backup configuration settings ?
I have the documentation of common endpoints which zscaler has exposed as below
https://help.zscaler.com/zpa/obtaining-idp-configuration-details-using-api
But I didn't find any api specific to backup configurations.
